# How to target specific button in JQuery for foreach loop elements

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, foreach

When I click this "comment" button for posts in a foreach loop

```
<button type="button" class="commentBtn">
<i class="em em-thought_balloon"></i>
</button>
```

I'm trying to get this form to open

```
{!! Form::open(['method'=>'POST', 'style'=>'display: none;', 'class'=>'commentform']) !!}
{!! Form::textarea('Comment', null, ['size'=>'50x2']) !!}
{!! Form::button('Comment', ['type'=>'submit', 'class'=>'btn btn-primary']) !!}
{!! Form::button('Cancel', ['class'=>'btn btn-default cancelcomment']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

I am using Laravel, an the button is in a foreach loop in a blade template. The form itself is also in the foreach loop. When I click the button, my jQuery function is working, but it's opening the form for every post in my foreach loop instead of just the targeted post. This is the function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".commentform").hide();
       $(".commentBtn").click(function(e) {
          $(".commentform").show();
    });
});
```

How can I fix this function so that only the targeted button for the post opens the form? Rather than having the form open in every post displayed in the foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `.commentform` is a sibling of `.commentBtn`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".commentform").hide();
       $(".commentBtn").click(function(e) {
          $(this).siblings(".commentform").show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get comment form that comes directly after clicked button

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".commentform").hide();
   $(".commentBtn").click(function(e) {
      $(this).next(".commentform").show();
   });
});
```

Comment: Now when I click the button with that code, nothing opens

Comment: Opps!! If every `.commentform` comes after its `.commentBtn` then you can use `next` instead of `closest`

Comment: I've tried that as well, for some reason it doesn't work. Could it be because of the form? Both the form and the button are in the same parent element. And the button does come before the form

Comment: with `next` comment form must come directly after comment button

Comment: Ahh, that was it! Thank you!